# JRBeanCollectionDataSource - bean full value is not exporting

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using the `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` for exporting records as PDF format. So, I am passing List to `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` for creating dataSource. In the final generated file is not complete. Meaning like, let say

```
public class myClassTOBean {

  private String var;

  //getter and setter blah blah...

}
```

In this above class the variable `var` has the value as "`FULL STRING`" where as final generated report has the value as "`FULL STRIN`". why is happened like.
What could be the problem?

Here is the piece of code am using to export.

```
JasperPrint jPrint;
            try {   //dataSouce is List of BeanTO class
                JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource 
                              = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);
                jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperFileFullName,
                        paramMap, dataSource);
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jPrint);
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING,
                        ReportConstant.FILE_ENCODING);
                exporter.exportReport();
            }finally{
                //close stream
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your field is not large enough and is trimming its content. Extend the field (in iReport) and try again.

Comment: You mean the field size in jrxml right? It is still not working :(

Comment: recompile, and make sure the latest version of the .jasper file is deployed.